# Backup Dropbox: Copying zip failed because: There is no disk set for the backup named `Laravel`

Tags: php, laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MRSv.png)

C:\laragon\www\systemBackup
λ php artisan backup:run --only-db
Starting backup...
Dumping database carga_diamond...
Determining files to backup...
Zipping 1 files and directories...
Created zip containing 1 files and directories. Size is 841.25 KB
Copying zip to disk named dropbox...
**Copying zip failed because: There is no disk set for the backup named `Laravel`..**
Backup completed!

I have this error when trying to backup with laravel and dropbox using the library: spatie / laravel-backup.

Any solution? :(